# K-means over weighted graph in python

Tags: python, graph, k-means

Imagine that we have a graph and we want to run k-means algorithm. The difficulty is that graph is weighted and distances between nodes represented by weights.

Does anyone know a way how to find several centroids this such a graph with weights of edges not with nodes positions?

Comment: K-means is most commonly applied to a Euclidean domain, and requires at the very least a distance metric. What distance metric applies to your problem?

Comment: Yes, specifically in this case the distance between two vertex is latency (ping).

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question... graphs don't have "latency". What's your metric, shortest path? Then you probably want E/M (possibly with an APSP prepass).

Comment: Yes ,you're right, the shortest path from all nodes to all nodes is the right metric we use. Could you mention alternatives for EM algorithm if they exists?

Comment: How to transform the graph to input data for k-means?